# creating a static function in model that returns number of arrays using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, select

Hi i have this static function in my model that returns number of children and to be displayed in my views as select dropdown. My code returns all the number of children from 1 to 9 ive noticed that in number 10 it displays only 1 meaning no second digit. How will i able to do this that will display the second digits. And also when i put ---select one--- it will display "-" dashed only. Heres my model below

```
public static function getNumberOfChildren(){
    return array(
      1 =>'1',
      2 =>'2',
      3 =>'3',
      4 =>'4',
      5 =>'5',
      6 =>'6',
      7 =>'7',
      8 =>'8',
      9 =>'9',
      10 =>'10'
    );

  }
```

and in my controller

```
 $this->data['numberOfChildren'] = $this->dm->getNumberOfChildren();
```

any my views

```
<select name="number_of_children" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($numberOfChildren as $children): ?>
  <option ><?php echo $children['number_of_children']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

that will display all the numbers in the select dropdown. My problem here is the number 10 it will display only 1. Can someone help me figured this out? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="number_of_children" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($numberOfChildren as $children): ?>
  <option ><?php echo $children; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: yes thanks for that it helps a lot. so i can now use strings too. it would display now

Comment: hi how about my return array is 1 =>'yes' and my value in option is yes also i want it my value is 1

Comment: just place this inside the option tag: `value="<?php echo $children; ?>"`

Comment: yes that is correct but what if my return array is 1 => 'yes' 2 =>'no' ? when i put $test in my value it will display the value of value="Y" i want it to be value="1"

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using this `$children['number_of_children'];`

Use This

```
<select name="number_of_children" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($numberOfChildren as $children): ?>
  <option ><?php echo $children; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is static function, then u call function:

```
Model_name::function();
```

U Code:

```
<select name="number_of_children" class="form-control">
<? foreach(Model_name::getNumberOfChildren() as $key=>$children){ ?>
  <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$children?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

If you do not use short tags, you have to rewrite the code.